# Adding static route results in connection loss

Tags: routing, freenas, smb3

I have a freenas server and my main pc equipped with dual port gigabit lan cards so Ican use smb multichannel.

I also had to add routes from the freenas server to each of the main pcs lan cards via each of the servers nics.

After having had some problems and resetting the nics on the main pc and redoing the routes. I now cant even ping the freenas pc from the other computer with the routes active.

I'd appreciate any help since I have no Idea what's going in here.

rounting table main pc

```
C:\Users\thorn>netstat -rn
===========================================================================
Schnittstellenliste
  2...70 8b cd 57 17 97 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
  5...00 19 99 ab 93 1f ......Intel(R) 82576NS Gigabit Network Connection
  3...00 19 99 ab 93 1e ......Intel(R) 82576NS Gigabit Network Connection #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.2    192.168.0.112     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.2    192.168.0.123     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.2    192.168.0.104     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.112    281
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.123    281
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.104    281
    192.168.0.104  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.104    281
    192.168.0.112  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.112    281
    192.168.0.123  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.123    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.112    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.123    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.104    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.123    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.104    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.112    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.123    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.104    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.0.112    281
===========================================================================
Ständige Routen:
  Keine

IPv6-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
 If Metrik Netzwerkziel             Gateway
  3    281 ::/0                     fe80::1
  1    331 ::1/128                  Auf Verbindung
 15    331 2001::/32                Auf Verbindung
 15    331 2001:0:9d38:78cf:10fe:2112:3f57:ff8f/128
                                    Auf Verbindung
  3    281 2003:e4:83ca:ee16::/64   Auf Verbindung
  3    281 2003:e4:83ca:ee16:9904:9e10:b725:de99/128
                                    Auf Verbindung
  3    281 2003:e4:83ca:ee16:d909:48ec:52fe:111/128
                                    Auf Verbindung
  5    281 fe80::/64                Auf Verbindung
  3    281 fe80::/64                Auf Verbindung
  2    281 fe80::/64                Auf Verbindung
 15    331 fe80::/64                Auf Verbindung
 15    331 fe80::10fe:2112:3f57:ff8f/128
                                    Auf Verbindung
  3    281 fe80::9904:9e10:b725:de99/128
                                    Auf Verbindung
  2    281 fe80::accc:a7b1:f9dd:921e/128
                                    Auf Verbindung
  5    281 fe80::ad16:f110:d32b:ab36/128
                                    Auf Verbindung
  1    331 ff00::/8                 Auf Verbindung
  5    281 ff00::/8                 Auf Verbindung
  3    281 ff00::/8                 Auf Verbindung
  2    281 ff00::/8                 Auf Verbindung
 15    331 ff00::/8                 Auf Verbindung
===========================================================================
Ständige Routen:
  Keine
```

and on freenas after adding routes

```
    root@freenas:~ # netstat -rn                            
Routing tables                                          

Internet:                                               
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Ex
pire                                                    
127.0.0.1          link#4             UH          lo0   
192.168.0.0/24     link#1             U           em0   
192.168.0.104      00:19:99:d9:d8:b1  UHS        igb0   
192.168.0.109      link#1             UHS         lo0   
192.168.0.112      00:19:99:d9:d8:b0  UHS        igb1   
192.168.0.123      00:19:99:a1:98:3a  UHS         em0   
192.168.0.124      link#2             UHS         lo0   
192.168.0.125      link#3             UHS         lo0   

Internet6:                                              
Destination                       Gateway               
        Flags     Netif Expire                          
::1                               link#4                
        UH          lo0                                 
fe80::%lo0/64                     link#4                
        U           lo0                                 
fe80::1%lo0                       link#4                
        UHS         lo0
```

Comment: Provide output of your ping attempts, routing tables in your question.

Comment: So using ping I found out that from my main computer i cant ping the secondray nics of the server, while i can from my phone.